Why doesn't this python plugin show up in my filters menu?
I'm trying to code a Python Fu plugin for GIMP, but it doesn't appear in my menus. Is there a mistake in my code? How can I fix this? Thank you a lot for reading me!
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *
import random as rd

def encode(image, drawable):
    newDrawable = drawable
    width = pdb.gimp_image_width(image)
    height = pdb.gimp_image_height(image)
    initialLayer = pdb.gimp_image_get_active_layer(image)
    title1 = ""
    title2 = ""
    for k in range(10):
        title1 += str(rd.randint(0,10))
        title2 += str(rd.randint(0,10))
    layer1 = pdb.gimp_layer_new(image, width, height, 0, "title1", 100, 0)
    layer2 = pdb.gimp_layer_new(image, width, height, 0, "title2", 100, 0)
    image.add_layer(layer1)
    image.add_layer(layer2)
    # Passe en revue l'intégralité des pixels
    for x in range (width):
        for y in range(height):
            #Lecture
            pdb.gimp_image_set_active_layer(image, initialLayer)
            newDrawable = image.layers[2]
            pixel = pdb.gimp_drawable_get_pixel(newDrawable, x, y)[1]
            #Mélange aléatoire des valeurs RVB
            newPixel1 = (rd.randint(0,pixel[0]+1), rd.randint(1,pixel[1]+1), rd.randint(2,pixel[2]+1))
            newPixel2 = (pixel[0] - newPixel1[0], pixel[1]- newPixel1[1], pixel[2]- newPixel1[2])
            #Écriture
            pdb.gimp_image_set_active_layer(image, layer1)
            newDrawable = image.layers[1]
            pdb.gimp_drawable_set_pixel(newDrawable, x, y, 3, newPixel1)
            pdb.gimp_drawable_update(newDrawable, 0, 0, width, height)
            pdb.gimp_image_set_active_layer(image, layer2)
            newDrawable = image.layers[0]
            pdb.gimp_drawable_set_pixel(newDrawable, x, y, 3, newPixel2)
            pdb.gimp_drawable_update(newDrawable, 0, 0, width, height)


register(
    "python_fu_encode",
    "Encodes an image into two ones.",
    "Creates two layers. For each pixel, a random amount of intensity will be removed and added to one of the layers ; the other layer gets the rest.",
    "Scapin", "Scapin", "2024",
    "Encode",
    "<Image>/Filters/Encode"
    "RGB"
    [
        (PF_IMAGE, "image", "Takes current image", None),
        (PF_DRAWABLE, "drawable", "Input layer", None)
    ],
    [],
    encode)

main()

I tried:

changing the plugin file pathes
reinstalling/updating GIMP
changing the structure of the register function


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

if you have some documentation for plugins in GIMP then you should add it in question (not in comments)

in How do I install Gimp-Python on windows? - Stack Overflow I found text "If you don't see the plugin in the menu it is likely a syntax error that doesn't let it run its registration code" and there is link to Debugging python-fu scripts in Windows . I can only suggest to use print() to see which part of code is executed - and start GIMP in console to see outputs.
